# Dll load failed in python

Tags: python

I'm using "edidistance" package.from this package there is error.

from .bycython import eval
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

how can solve it?

note : msvcr71.dll,msvcp71.dll are installed properly on my machine

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem
Fix 1. Reinstall Library
In most cases, the error occurs when you import a library. The cause of the error may be incorrect/incomplete installation or incompatibility of the library. In this case, you can try reinstalling the library to see whether the problem can be solved. Please refer to the following steps:

Step 1: Identify the library that causes the error "ImportError: Dll Load Failed: The specified module could not be found." Usually, you can find the culprit in the output lines just above the error.

Step 2: You can use the following commands to uninstall and install a library (numpy is the name of a Python library).

pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
Sometimes, the library may be outdated and you need to install the latest version. In this case, you should uninstall the library first, then update the pip, and finally install the library again.

Besides, if the error occurs, because the module is too new, you can solve the problem by installing the module with a specified version.

ix 2. Configure Environment Variables
If the above method can't solve the problem, you should check whether the environment variables are set correctly. Sometimes, the environment variables may change without reasons. In this case, you should configure the environment variables again. Please refer to the following steps:

Step 1: Identify which Python distribution you are using (e.g. Anaconda).

Step 2: Right-click on My Computer/This PC icon and choose Properties. Click Advanced system settings > Environment Variables. Click Path variable under User variables box or System variables box. Click the corresponding Edit button.

Step 3: A new window will pop up. Then, click New button to add the following 3 variables:

X:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
X:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
X:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

and in first solve i get answer